# nodejs exec Wget command

Tags: node.js, wget

I’m writing a nodejs application for download entire web sites using “wget” unix command, but I have a problem with some urls inside the downloaded pages, .html appeares at the end of the files e.g

```
<img src=“images/photo.jpeg.html”> or <script src=“js/scripts.js.html”>
```

The code i’m using is the following:

```
    var util = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child,
    url = 'http://www.example.com/';
child = exec('wget --mirror -p --convert-links --html-extension -e robots=off -P /destination_folder/ ' + url,
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

N.B If i use this command (wget --mirror -p --html-extension --convert-links -e robots=off -P . http://www.example.com) directly on the Unix shell it works correctly.

**Edit**:
this is the log returned after running the nodejs script:

```
--2017-04-04 11:49:49--  http://www.example.com/css/style.min.css
Reusing existing connection to www.example.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
File ‘/destination_folder/www.example.com/css/style.min.css.html’ not modified on server. Omitting download.

FINISHED --2017-04-04 11:50:11--
Total wall clock time: 22s
Downloaded: 50 files, 1.2M in 1.4s (855 KB/s)
/destination_folder/www.example.com/css/style.min.css.html: No such file or directory
Converting links in /destination_folder/www.example.com/css/style.min.css.html... nothing to do.
exec error: Error: stderr maxBuffer exceeded
```

I don’t understand where is the problem, could you help me please?

Thank you

Comment: You should probably describe in more detail how you've determined that it isn't working. Is `error` set (if so, what is the message)? Is there `stderr` output (if so, what does it contain)? Are neither of these the case but you're still not seeing anything in your destination directory? Something else?

Comment: Is Node.JS executing the same version of ``wget`` that you execute from command line?

Comment: @tiblu I think is the same version, How can I check?

Comment: @SMadry ``exec('wget --version')`` and run the same in terminal.

Comment: @tiblu is the same: 1.19.1

Answer (score 0):

`exec` uses a buffer between `stdout` and `sterr` which is limited.

If the files to download are big the buffer may run out of space.
Try using `spawn` intestad of `exec`.
For your reference:
[Difference between `spawn` and `exec` of Node.js](http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html)